# Javascript, submitting string to JSON file through server, line breaks not working

Tags: javascript, json

having a bit of an issue. I am using Firebase with my project and it stores all data in a JSON file. When I am creating the object to push to Firebase in my code like this:

```
customers.child(uniqueId).set({
    first_name: addCustomerDialogFirstName.value.toString(),
    last_name: addCustomerDialogLastName.value.toString(),
    email: addCustomerDialogEmail.value.toString(),
    organization: addCustomerDialogOrganization.value.toString(),
    address: addCustomerDialogAddressOne.value.toString() + ', ' +
             addCustomerDialogAddressTwo.value.toString() + '\\n' +
             addCustomerDialogAddressCity.value.toString() + ', ' +
             addCustomerDialogAddressState.value.toString() + ' - ' +
             addCustomerDialogZip.value.toString(),
    phone: addCustomerDialogPhoneCountryCode.value.toString() +
           addCustomerDialogPhoneAreaCode.value.toString() +
           addCustomerDialogPhoneRest.value.toString()
});
```

I'm confused how to get this to display properly in a JSON file. When I look at the JSON file on Firebase it just reads `(value of address two)\\n(value of address - city)` and doesn't see that the `\\n` isn't part of a string. Any idea how to get this to display properly in my JSON file? I've never really worked with JSON before this so I'm a bit of a noob. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you escaping the new line character? It should just be `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong here, `\\n`. It's just `\n`. Check [escape sequence characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx)